# Custom f.label for a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I'm using f.label in ERB, how can I change the output without completing renaming the symbols in code and the database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

`<%= f.label :some_label, "Some Groovy Label Text" %>`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can use:

```
f.label(:title, "A short title")
```